# Merge/Synonymize GTWP GWT-Platform

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Is it possible to merge/synonymize:

[gwtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwtp) and [gwt-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-platform)

I don't have enough rep in these tags to start it.

They are the exact same tag and they have the **exact same** wiki. *(see below)*

There is around 200 of first one and 300 of second one, so a bit too much to retag it. Though it's doable, it would flood the home page with old questions.

---

## Wikis

**GWTP:**

> GWTP, or gwt-platform, is a framework to facilitate the development of large applications for the Google Web Toolkit (GWT). It facilitates the use of a Model-View-Presenter (MVP) architecture and it offers a command pattern supporting undo and redo.
>
> The framework is hosted at: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP

**GWT-Platform:**

> gwt-platform, or GWTP, is a framework to facilitate the development of large applications for the Google Web Toolkit (GWT). It facilitates the use of a Model-View-Presenter (MVP) architecture and it offers a command pattern supporting undo and redo.
>
> The framework is hosted at: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP

Comment: approved by community vote